# Collapse all policies nodes inside Microsoft Business Rule Composer

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013

I have a lot of BRE policies, which make the BRE composer UI hard to deal with. So my question is how can I collapse all policies nodes inside Microsoft Business Rule Composer using a single click, command, or keys combination?

Do we have any option to open the BRE with collapsed nodes by default?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the Compose doesn't not have any such shortcuts like Visual Studio.

Perhaps you could use a tool like AutoHotKey to send multiple Left/Up keys.